# Apache passing subdomain to alternative path

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration

I am new to Apache and am trying to map

> www.subdomain.mycompany.com:8083

TO

> www.mycompany.com:8083/subdomain

But the subdomain can be anything its not predetermined.

We are using running **Apache 2.2.15**. There are proxypasses setup at the moment in the `.conf` file.

I have to pass this to a proxypass:

> ProxyPass /myapplication https://serv123.internal:5000/myapplication/subdomain
>
> ProxyPassReverse /myapplication https://serv123.internal:5000/myapplication/subdomain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apache Module **mod_vhost_alias**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAlias *.example.com
     VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3/
     VirtualScriptAlias /var/www/%-3/
</VirtualHost>
```

The access for URL *http://**subdomain**.example.com* will map to /var/www/**subdomain**/
-3 refers to the third part of URL, as -2 refers to **example**.

ServerAlias directive prevents a error when accessing http://example.com/. Without the directive, this access will try to redirect to **/var/www/_/**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As part of this I have to use the Apache server to pass the url. I added further detail above.